# dilemma with on change event dropdown

Tags: jquery

Hello so here is what I am doing :

```
  $("#categorys").change(function () {
//$(document).on('click', '#categorys', function(){ 
        alert('changed or clicked');     
 });
```

when I use the .change nothing happens, no errors on the js debugger, when I use the on click event for the same dropdown it returns the alert. I would to be able to alert(this.val) once the dropdown value changes please help

Comment: Are you adding the `#categorys` element to the page dynamically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you use event delegation for your `click` event, you need to do the same for `change` event:

```
$(document).on('change', '#categorys', function(){ 
    alert('changed or clicked');     
});
```

Btw, this behavior only happens when your select has been added dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to solve the matter:

```
$(document).on('change', '#categorys', function(){ 
        alert($(this).val());     


    });
```

Comment: If that solved your problem, then it's almost certainly due to the fact that `#categorys` was being added to the DOM after the event was bound. The original syntax was perfectly valid, but requires the element to exist at the time it is bound. By using the `on` syntax you are actually binding the event to the document, allowing it to catch events which bubble from dynamically added elements.